# ORDINALstring in fmtcount generates wrong number

Tags: lyx, fmtcount

I am trying to redefine the format of `Part` in Lyx (in Italian), it should look as follows:

```
SEZIONE PRIMA
TESTO DEL TITOLO, RIGA 1
TESTO DEL TITOLO, RIGA 2
```

i.e.:

```
FIRST SECTION
TEXT OF TITLE, LINE1
TEXT OF TITLE, LINE2
```

This is my attempt so far:

```
\addto\captionsitalian{%
  \renewcommand{\partname}%
    {SEZIONE}%
  \renewcommand{\thepart}%
    {\ORDINALstring{part}[f]}%
}
```

Part text looks like this:

```
\begin_layout Part
TITOLO LINEA 1
\begin_inset Newline newline
\end_inset

TITOLO LINEA 2
\end_layout
```

The strange thing is, that this is rendered in pdf as follows:

```
SEZIONE NOVANTADUESIMA
TITOLO LINEA 1
TITOLO LINEA 2
```

(I.e. "Section 92nd")

However, if I use `ordinalstring` or `Ordinalstring`, the section counter is correctly rendered as `prima` and `Prima` ("first"), respectively.

What I do not understand is, where does 92 come from in the upper case version, and of course, how could I achieve the correct number there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about LyX, but I do know that `fmtcount` cannot be used like that.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{itnumpar}

\addto\captionsitalian{\renewcommand{\partname}{SEZIONE}}
\renewcommand{\thepart}{\MakeUppercase{\ordinalef{part}}}

\begin{document}

\part{AAA\\BBB}

\part{CCC\\DDD}

\end{document}
```

(I used `article` just because it doesn't make page breaks at `\part`.)

[image]